# Resources in src/main/resources are not accessible to tomcat7 maven plugin?

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

When I put xml resources such as spring configuration files, logging ... etc in the src/main/resources these files are not readable by my application when I run it in the embedded tomcat plugin. However moving these files into src/main/java fixes the problem.

Here is the plugin definition that I am using:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/</path>
            <contextFile>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgres.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
                <goal>run-war</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Why can the resources be found when I put them in src/main/java but not when I put them in src/main/resources when running `mvn tomcat7:run`

**UPDATE:** I am using eclipse with m2e I can run the application just fine using Run As > Run on Server which is pointed to a local tomcat server. The folder structure is correct, eclipse settings are coming from the pom.xml via m2e.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid 'log4jConfigLocation' parameter: class path resource [log4j-config.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

in this case log4j-config.xml is in src/main/resources, there are few more exceptions like that saying that files on src/main/resources folder don't exist.

**Update 2:** The problem turned out to be a `<resources>` element in the parent POM that was causing the .xml files to not be included in the generated output.

Comment: It's a bit weird as I perso use that without any issue
what kind of error do you have ? Any sample to reproduce that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when eclipse try to find the files which are defined by your application..it links the src to src/main/java and src/main/resources..could you see the following entries in .class file of maven generated for eclipse..

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>

/**all repository entries are also here**/
</classpath>
```

then for the resources first the tomcat checks whether they are in the resources (and also checks them in the java folder)

Comment: I guess the maven spring folder strcture you created is not having the identification of resources folder as SRC folder path starting point

Comment: I don't see a trace of the word eclipse in the question. And not a tag saying eclipse either. Why are you assuming he is using eclipse? There are other IDEs you know. And this question does not have anything to do with any IDEs. It is a question of resources being available or not.

Comment: @maba sorry for assuming wrongly. my idea here for him is to intimate to him that there might be some wrong in the creation of folder structure in maven.As an example i put the eclipse for him so that it might be useful for him for figuring out where it is getting wrong.